# Set Dropdownlist selected item with database value in listview

Tags: asp.net

i have dropdownlist of users list which is coming dynamically from database.i have filled the dropdownlist using object datasource on inserting in the listview control it is working fine.
my problem is that when listview bind rows, I want the option specified in the database to be selected in the dropdown list,but the dropdownlist is selected with the default option after filling
for example in this picture
[image]

this picture loaded 2 records from database in the listview
every thing is fine but in dropdownlist (ReferTo) i want after bind listview or during bind listview every dropdown must selected item will be set with database values but every record's dropdownlist still show me first item(default item "select one")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting SelectedValue of a data bound DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746745/setting-selectedvalue-of-a-data-bound-dropdownlist)

Comment: no ty i updated my post plz help if you can

Comment: You need to upload some code. Otherwise its simply guessing what you are doing and how to help you. Do not upload the code as screenshots. Post using the appropriate code tags for formatting.